# Wordpress changes don't reflect

Tags: wordpress, caching, static-pages

I have a wordpress website with a static homepage. When I make some changes in the Page editor and click Update, it does not reflect in my website homepage, although clicking on Preview Changes from within the editor shows my changes.

I tried deleting everything, and just put "Hello World", disabled all my plugins, deleted the files from my custom theme, cleared the plugin cache, still the problem persists.

I am really stumped. Is there anything else I can try?

EDIT: It may be a problem with my DNS. Looking into that.

Comment: can you share me homepage content code?

Comment: Means where you want to show the content.

Comment: Man take a snapshot from your page file of homepage.

Comment: https://s32.postimg.org/qug6mn3hh/page_editor.png

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to change in http://foart.space/art-local-artists-locals/ edit side. and check it on the home page.

Comment: Since the permalink in the previous screen shot is causing confusing. Here is the right screen shot of the current status: https://s32.postimg.org/qug6mn3hh/page_editor.png

As you can see, I am editing the right file, and the "Hello World" in the page is not showing up.

Comment: I just added a new page and set that as the front page, still no joy.

Comment: After some time with yet another tech support, he says it could be a problem with my DNS config. It is actually my boss's hosting, so need to check with them as well.

Comment: Thank you Shahid Thaika for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not displaying anything at all or just not updating?

If it is not displaying anything at all it does the Homepage page template echo the contents?

Is there the_content(); in that template?